# Is there any open source real road map routing implementation?

Tags: c++, dijkstra, a-star

I wonder if open source implementation exist for searching optimal point-to-point route on a real map with a big number of nodes? Like is there an implementation for Dijkstra and A*?

Comment: did you try to use google ? there are many implementations of these algorithms ... http://code.google.com/p/a-star-algorithm-implementation/

Comment: Yap Ive seen this one. Its written not for the real road maps though..

Comment: what do you mean with "for real road maps"? its performance ? or if you can input real map data without modificating it ?

Answer (score 1):

[Gosmore](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore) is an open-source router for OpenStreetMap data. By downloading a OSM file, you can do real road routing.

Comment: There is a link to Gosmore's svn repository! http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/gosmore/